# how to display <head> tags when rendering html template

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

i am learning how to render html template via flask. the problem is the head tags of the below html file never get displayed. only the tags  is dislayed.
please let me know how to get the tags  displayed

**python code**:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for
from flask import request
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__) # Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
user = {'username': 'AWA'}
return render_template('index.html', title='Home', user=user)

@app.route('/layout')
def layout():
return render_template('layout.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

**CODE**:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    {% if title %}
            <title>{{ title }} - Microblog</title>
    {% else %}
        <title>Welcome to Microblog</title>
    {% endif %} 

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, {{ user.username }}!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think flask cares where in the HTML file your placeholders are (head vs body). Have you tried viewing the page source on your browser to see if the placeholders are getting removed? Have you tried using a simpler, known working placeholder in the head, e.g. `<title>{{ user.username }}</title>`? Or tried putting `{{ title }}` in the body to make sure it gets converted as you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data in the `<head>` tag is normally not visible to the end user. It is normally used for metadata, css files, and sometimes js. Also, the `<title>` tag is purely for the browser to display in the title bar. You might want the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header tag.

You can read more about the head tag here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head, and the title tag here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head

EDIT:

You could use the `<header>` tag in conjunction with `<h1>` to make a visible title, here's a quick example (code not tested):

```html
<html>
    <head>
    {% if title %}
            <title>{{ title }} - Microblog</title>
    {% else %}
        <title>Welcome to Microblog</title>
    {% endif %} 

    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            {% if title %}
                <h1>{{ title }} - Microblog</h1>
            {% else %}
                <h1>Welcome to Microblog</h1>
            {% endif %}
        </header>
        <h3>Hello, {{ user.username }}!</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please tell me hpw to modify the html code so that the code the title tag can be shown up

Comment: The title tag cant show up as far as I know, but you could use a header element with an h1 element inside of it (with the title content). (And change the Hello, {{user.username}} to h3)

Comment: @LetsamrIt added example code in my answer